# passing address of a function with specific return and arguments type to another function accepting generic type functions with generic type arguments

Tags: c

I'm trying to pass a function of type:

> int *(*)(int *, int *)

to a function accepting as argument a:

> void *(*)(void *, void *)

is there any way to do that ?

Comment: Have you tried?  If it didn't work, what was the problem?

Comment: I keep getting this 
error: incompatible function pointer types passing 'int *(*)(int *, int *)' to parameter of type
      'void *(*)(void *, void *)' [-Werror,-Wincompatible-function-pointer-types]

Comment: No, you can't do that.

Comment: What does the receiving function do with the function pointer? Does it call the pointed-to function, and if so, with what arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always cast stuff explicitly in C -- so you can cast `(void *(*)(void *, void *))func` to pass the function pointer.  The problem is that if the callee then tries to call through the function pointer without first casting it back to `int *(*)(int *, int *)`, the result is undefined behavior.

Now it may be the case that on your specific ABI this is likely to work anyways (all pointer types have the same representation, and are passed as arguments in the same way), so you might get away with it, but its still undefined behavior.  This is a good example of where the standard underspecifies things which are likely to be abused as a result.  Arguably this sort of thing should at least be implementation defined, not undefined.

Comment: thank you for this clarification, that was helpful and my problem is solved now :)